# locating an element on an iframe within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Hi I need some help with locating the button on an iframe which I think is within another iFrame. I tried everything[image] that I could find but got no success. I can't copy-paste the whole code but have attached the screenshot that explains the tree.

Comment: I can't check if my code is working since your question is missing debugging details. So, I just guessed. Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.swg-dialog"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='publicatioId=barpage.com']"))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, div[data-test-id='close-button']).click()
```

When you finished working with elements inside the iframe don't forget to switch back to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

In case you prefer using XPath, not CSS Selectors, the above code can be easily converted to XPath expressions

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@class,'swg-dialog')]"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'publicatioId=barpage.com')]"))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, //div[@data-test-id='close-button']).click()
```

Probably you will have to add waiting until the elements are available etc. In this case `WebDriverWait` should be used

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first 2 lines of code that you suggested, worked fine and I was able to identify and switch to the 2 iframes with minor adjustments. However, the close button is still not willing to get identified. I tried  

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//div[data-test-id='close-button']")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@data-test-id='close-button')]")

Comment: Well, `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//div[data-test-id='close-button']")` can not work since `"//div[data-test-id='close-button']"` is XPath expresson, not CSS_SELECTOR.

Comment: You did not share ALL your Selenium code including the link to the page you working on. In order to help you we are missing debugging details

Comment: I tried that with the XPATH as well but no luck. Will keep trying

Comment: If so - why you accepted the answer? In case it was useful, as you wrote, you could just upvote it...

Comment: if you can share all your code and a link I can try help more, as I wrote.

Comment: I accepted the answer because with your suggestion, I was able to locate and switch to the iframes fine, so there is some progress. cannot share the code on a public platform else I would have.

Comment: I see.. But you do can upvote, this would be the right way. here and generally. In case several answers were useful you can upvote each of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249049/discussion-between-chauhany-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter in first iframe to enter the second after.

try this code

```
iframe = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("XpathOf1frame")    
navegador.switch_to.frame(iframe)
iframe2 = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("XpathOf2frame")    
navegador.switch_to.frame(iframe2)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('XpathOfButton').click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Matheus Leles. In theory, I know what to do, that is, Locate iframe1 and then switch to it, then locate iframe2 and switch to it and then find the close button.  But XPATH is the problem.